# "Packages can't be authenticated" during apt-get install on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

I am trying to download `gcc` using `apt-get install` on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty, but when apt-get is trying to download the file I receive an error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!   
libc6 libc6-i686 binutils libgomp1 gcc-4.3 gcc linux-libc-dev libc6-dev Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y 

Err http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/main libc6 2.9-4ubuntu6.3  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Err http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main binutils 2.19.1-0ubuntu3   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Err http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main libgomp1 4.3.3-5ubuntu4   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Err http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main gcc-4.3 4.3.3-5ubuntu4   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Err http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main gcc 4:4.3.3-1ubuntu1   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main libc6 2.9-4ubuntu6.3   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main libc6-i686 2.9-4ubuntu6.3   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main linux-libc-dev 2.6.28-19.66   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main libc6-dev 2.9-4ubuntu6.3   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.9-4ubuntu6.3_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-i686_2.9-4ubuntu6.3_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 
Failed to fetch http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.19.1-0ubuntu3_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Failed to fetch http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.3/libgomp1_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Failed to fetch http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.3/gcc-4.3_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Failed to fetch http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_4.3.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80] 
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_2.6.28-19.66_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.9-4ubuntu6.3_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80] 

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

`apt-get update` and `--fix-missing` are not solving the problem.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 13):

I managed to solved the problem by editing the /etc/apt/sources.list file and replacing all instances of **archive.ubuntu.com** and **security.ubuntu.com** with  **old-releases.ubuntu.com**. After that, I ran sudo apt-get update to update the indexes.

Comment: A more detailed explanation of this solution is available in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/563316).

Answer (score 5):

This little script performs the correct string replacements in sources.list and updates the package list:

```
cd /etc/apt
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.bak
sudo sed -i "s/archive./old-releases./g" sources.list
sudo sed -i "s/\/security./\/old-releases./g" sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: note that `.` in `sed` matches not only the period character but any other character. in this case, this makes no difference, but it could. period can be matched using `\.` or `[.]`.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ – Jaunty is missing.

Your Version of Ubuntu is too old. The Jaunty repository is not more available. I think you need to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the same ubuntu version jaunty, and update the url of the repository of apt-get to a newer version to be able to download the deb files?

Comment: @DreX Yes its possible, but no really good idea. The problem are Dependences. App X need glic >=2.10 or app Y needs >qt4.6 etc.

Comment: @DreX maybe you will want install only small depen app, then can do it :)

Comment: @DreX - You'll want to use an LTS version for the longest support times.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by (re)moving the multiarch dpkg config file, re-installing dpgk, then trying an upgrade..

Fails:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Fails:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Succeeds:

```
sudo mv /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch.backup
sudo apt-get install dpkg
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me today, on Debian Jessie, tried:

- `apt-get update`: Did not helped
- `apt-get clean`: Did not helped
- `apt-key update`: Did not helped
- `rm -fr /var/cache/apt/*`: Did not helped
- `rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*`: Solved the problem (don't forget `apt-get update`).

`apt-get update` will happily recreate the `partial/` directory and the `lock` file, don't worry.